# Read file name for 5 to 10 digit account number, is this possible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I am attempting to write a program in VB.net which will output some values in to a text file. Please be patient with me as I am very new to VB.net.

What I have so far is below:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim str As String
    For Each File As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text)
        str = str & File & "|" & System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Split("-")(0).Trim & "|" & System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Split("-")(0).Trim & "||" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "|" & Environment.NewLine
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\output\output.txt", str)

End Sub
```

Results of output file (output.txt) when button3 is clicked are below:

```
C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\2356851-Kathy Winkler - Family Investments.pdf|2356851|2356851||04/10/2013|

C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\58736 -Katrina Armon - Sandlewood Homes Co.pdf|58736|58736||04/10/2013|

C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\Karen Cooper - 001548 - Famtime.pdf|Karen Cooper|Karen Cooper||04/10/2013|
```

My code so far does exactly what I want it to do, the only thing is that I want to make the code smarter but don’t know how. Smarter as in is there a way I can make the below code only pick up the 5 to 10 digit account number seen in the filename, and if no account number exists in the file name to bring up a message box?

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Split("-")(0).Trim & "|" & System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Split("-")(0).Trim
```

As you can see from the last line of the output…

```
C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\Karen Cooper - 001548 - Famtime.pdf|Karen Cooper|Karen Cooper||04/10/2013|
```

…the customers name “Karen Cooper” is being displayed in both areas where the account number should be displayed. This is why I need to make this code smarter somehow have it search the file name for a 5 to 10 digit account number to display it after the file name as see in the other 2 examples.

Please let me know if this is possible. And do let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give this a try.  I haven't had a chance to test it but it should work

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim str As String
    For Each File As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim strs as String() = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Split("-")
        Dim AccountNum as int = 0
        For each section in strs()
            ' Loop through each section separated by - and try to cast it to an int
             ' you may want to use cLong instead
            Try
               AccountNum = cInt(section.trim())
               exit for
            Catch
            End Try
        Next
      ' DO LOGIC HERE TO BUILD OUTPUT with the account num now known
    Next

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\output\output.txt", str)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for your response but I am not sure on how to build the logic for my output with your adjustments. I have this but it doesnt work :( 'code' str = str() & File & "|" & AccountNum & "|" & AccountNum & "||" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & "|" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value & "|" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value & "||" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "|" & Environment.NewLine 'code'

Comment: Sorry, using Str use the modified code above (change str to section)

Comment: Im having a problem building your code. I'm getting an error and not sure why on this 'For Each section In strs()' the error is saying "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array". Not sure what that means. I have my logic built which is 'str = str & File & "|" & AccountNum & "|" & "_" & "||" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & "|" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value & "|" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value & "||" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "|" & Environment.NewLine' Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is you some simple logic .... ofcouse you can just do something like finding the filename first but here you go

```
    Dim returnval As String = ""
    Dim s As String = "C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\Karen Cooper - 001548 - Famtime.pdf|Karen Cooper|Karen Cooper||04/10/2013|"
    For Each p As String In s

        If IsNumeric(p) Then
            returnval += p
        Else
            'MsgBox("no")
        End If
    Next
```

msgbox(returnval) will hold all your numbers 5-10 , depends on how specific you want to get from here

to break apart the filenames

```
 'This will extract and return the filename from the specified path and filename.
 '
 Dim filePath As String = "c:\MyDirectory\MYFile.txt"
 Dim slashPosition As Integer = filePath.LastIndexOf("\")
 Dim filenameOnly As String = filePAth.Substring(slashPosition + 1)

 MsgBox(filenameOnly)

 *FOUND AT LINK http://www.vbforfree.com/274/extract-and-retrieve-the-filename-from-a-path/*
```

then manipulate your string from there as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

How about yor file name ?

```
C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\Karen Cooper - 001548 - Famtime.pdf
```

Fairly, It should be

```
C:\DirectoryTest\Clients\001548 - Karen Cooper - Famtime.pdf
```

Comment: Yes, fixing the file name would fix this problem. But I cannot depend on my users to ensure the file name is always like this. This is why i need some smart code to check this. Is it possible to do what I am requesting?

Comment: @Andrea: my 2c - users will always outsmart your program, so training is usually in place to help workflow.

Comment: @Andrea: So, you have to make a function that parse / split the filename .. and there's no number in their name

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using RegEx to extract the account number.  A side benefit of using RegEx is that you can store the RegEx pattern outside of your code, such as in a configuration file, so if you ever need to modify the pattern, you could do so easily without recompiling your application.

```
Function GetAccountNumber(fileName As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String = ".*?(?<acct>\d{5,10}).*?"
    Dim regEx As New Regex(pattern)
    Dim match As Match = regEx.Match(fileName)
    Dim accountNumber As String = Nothing
    If match.Success Then
        Dim group As Group = match.Groups("acct")
        If group.Success Then
            accountNumber = group.Value
        End If
    End If
    Return accountNumber
End Function
```

In the above example, I am using the following RegEx pattern to find the five to ten digit number in the string:

> `.*?(?<acct>\d{5,10}).*?`

The `.*?` at the beginning and end of the pattern means any character, any number of times.  The question mark means it's non-greedy.  In other words, it only matches as many characters as necessary.  By making it non-greedy, it will not steal-away any of the digits from the account number.

The parentheses surround the part of the string we are looking for (the account number).  The `?<acct>` at the beginning of the parenthetical group a name by which we can refer to it.  In this case, I named the group `acct`.  The `\d` means any digit character.  The `{5,10}` means repeated between five and ten times.